# excel vba file name extraction without file extension

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following excel vba code to get the txt files from a folder and put them into excel.

```
Sub testfilelistfromfolder()
Dim varDirectory As Variant
Dim flag As Boolean
Dim i As Integer
Dim strDirectory As String

strDirectory = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
i = 1
flag = True
varDirectory = Dir(strDirectory & "*.txt", vbNormal)
Range("B3:B82").Select
Selection.ClearContents

While flag = True
    If varDirectory = "" Then
        flag = False
    Else
        Cells(i + 2, 2) = varDirectory
        varDirectory = Dir
        i = i + 1
    End If
Wend

End Sub
```

so my question is: 

Is there a way to list the txt filenames without the .txt extension? 
or should I add a line to trim the names?
something like this:

```
variable = Left(Sheet1.[A1],InStr(Sheet1.[A1],".")-1)
```

and if so,
 how should i adapt this to my original code, where should i put it? 
is it also possible to replace Sheet1 with the active sheet parameter?How?

thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd tackle is thusly

```
Else
        sStr = InStr(varDirectory, ".txt")
        Cells(i + 2, 2) = Left(varDirectory, sStr - 1)
```

Comment: Where exactly should I put these three lines in my code? @mrbungle

Comment: @AHC just replace your `Else` with this `Else`

Comment: yes, thanks.
however, i had to add
`varDirectory = Dirv` and 
`i = i + 1`
to avoid unlimited results, to activate the loop.

Comment: well yeah, I assumed that part was a given, guess i should have said replace the first two lines :) glad it worked

Answer (score 0):

```
 flNAME = Left(Cells(1, 1).Value,Len(Cells(1, 1).Value)-4)
```

This grabs the Value of the cell indicated and trims the last for characters off. Obviously if it is not a dot with a three letter extension you will have extra characters. For example, .XLSX would leave the dot.

The code is going to assume that you means the cells of the active sheet. If you want to get data from a different sheet then you need to add code to select the new sheet.

I am not sure what you are trying to use if for so it is hard to say where you will need it in your code at.

Comment: i want to repeat this in specified range "B3:B82"
by the way, should I add flNAME as string? Could you please explain more?